# How to remote access MySQL installed on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL installation on windows server 2012 R2 on a remote server. Which was accessible earlier from my local computer over internet. But recently my local IP is changed, by then I am unable to access MySQL.

I am using MySQL as database with my application building on C# MVC with Entity Framework 6.

MySQL is not accessible through Workbench either now.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here:
[MySQL:Can’t connect to MySQL server (10060) from remote client](https://indiandeve.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/mysqlcant-connect-to-mysql-server-10060-from-remote-client/)